# Get table-name from an arbitrary %ROWTYPE or RECORD value

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

### Desired setup

To *improve the elegance* of some code, I was wondering whether it was/is possible to do the opposite of [%ROWTYPE variable from table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549823/rowtype-variable-from-table-name) — extract a table's name ***from*** a `%ROWTYPE` or `RECORD` (most relevantly, after it's been passed into a function which accepts the `ANYELEMENT` pseudo-type):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generic_function(row_data ANYELEMENT)
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
    table_name TEXT = get_table_name(row_data);
BEGIN
    -- [ work goes here ]
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

### Current workaround

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generic_function(row_data ANYELEMENT, table_name TEXT) 
RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN
    -- [ work goes here ]
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The workaround feels *a touch* redundant, if you can imagine how it might look in the calling code:

```
SELECT INTO x * FROM mytable WHERE foo = bar; 
PERFORM generic_function(x,'mytable');
```

### Elegant-but-stupid solution

To allow the call-signature I show up-top, the best solution I could come up with is a high-overhead guess-and-check approach which would probably be an *extremely* bad idea to use in production. You can find the sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/78cf0/1/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution. Use [**`pg_typeof()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generic_function(row_data ANYELEMENT)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   table_name text := pg_typeof($1);
BEGIN
   RETURN table_name;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Obviously, this can only work for registered composite types. *Every* table or view falls into this category. But not derived tables.

Test:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (id int);
SELECT generic_function(NULL::foo);
```

[Here is a search for related answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[plpgsql]%20anyelement%20pg_typeof%20is%3aanswer)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any solution on plpgsql level. Theoretically you can do it for some cases in C extension, but the code will be pretty complex. Postgres, PLpgSQL is designed as static, type rigid environment - and dynamic SQL doesn't change it too much (design prefer speed, less memory usage). Just don't design too dynamic code inside Postgres.

Comment: I forgot, yes - but for nontrivial queries it should not work.